# How is DocumentSet Capture Version data stored in Content Database

Tags: 2010, sql-server, document-set, versioning, content-database

Is it possible to know how a "DocumentSet Capture Version" data is stored in SQL Server Content Database ? (Not using OM but directly).

Comment: Its not advisable to query Content Database. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AmalHashim Yes i agree. I just want to see the table structure. Its on a dev machine.

Comment: You can use SQL profiler to track down.. But its not recommended

Answer (score 1):

The SharePoint SQL Schema details are not documented. Its not documented because Microsoft don't want any one to touch it. There are complex job's etc running on these tables and a simple read operation can bring down the farm.

SharePoint comes with various API to access the data.